# Fetch from one git server and push to another server using Jenkins

Tags: java, git, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a local git server (centOS) where everyone pushes their work to that repository. Jenkins manages to build whatever in that repository is, overnight. Lately I've got a Git Enterprise account. I've been wondering if there's any way to force Jenkins to 1) Only pulls the code from the local server and 2) Whenever a build was successful, sends the code to git enterprise remote repository.

I'm using Jenkins v. 1.458

Answer (score 7, accepted):

well, one option would be to just create a script that does this from bash...but...

You can just add two git repositories under the "source code management" section **after installing the [Multiple SCMs plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Multiple+SCMs+Plugin)**, and then specify that you want to build REPOLOCALNAME/branch, and then at the end under 'Git publisher' specify you want to merge and push to the remote branch. (ie. BranchToPush=branchname and TargetRemoteName= REMOTEREPONAME)

*Remember, the names are specified under advanced options of the repository when you add it under the SCM section.

*I haven't tested this, there is a chance that it might let you only pull and push, from and to the same repository.

Comment: But do you know. how we can do this with a script?

Comment: It wasn't that easy, but I could finally manage to do it, and it was basically like what you said, thanks.

Comment: sorry for not being more explicit/replying sooner :S
I am glad to hear you got it working.
In the end did you have to do a custom bash script? or were you able to get it working from within jenkins?

Comment: bash script is what I avoid to use, I got it working within Jenkins.

Comment: @Peymankh can you you please share how did you do it? I'm adding two repos and building from the first, but the second one isn't added to .git/config, so the push done by the publisher fails. strangely enough, if I tell it to build from all repos, I can see in the log that its pulling from both, but still one the 1st one is added to .git/config

Comment: What if I need to do it from the Jenkinsfile in order to switch repo dynamically? I'm able to clone the second repo, but git context is always the first repo, even after an sh "cd second_repo"

Answer (score 0):

You could set up the push to Github as the last build step that is only run after everything else has succeeded and use the normal mechanisms for retrieving the code from the local git repository. There is no plugin that has this functionality at the moment.

Comment: Well, instead of GitHub I'm using GitEnt, but that's not the case. Ok so any suggestion on how to do it or maybe a tutorial?

Comment: Sorry, I misread. The process should be the same though -- for the repository that Jenkins uses, set up a new remote (once) and then push to it at the end of every build. There's a short tutorial on how to do that [here](http://thelucid.com/2008/12/02/git-setting-up-a-remote-repository-and-doing-an-initial-push/) for example.